Proper way to connect 4" corrugated drainage pipe into perpendicular 12" pipe
I'm installing a 4" corrugated/perforated plastic pipe into a drainage ditch (2-3ft deep "French drain") in my yard uphill from my house (which sits on a steep [wet] slope). There is already a 12" pipe (perhaps plastic/corrugated) buried in the ground along the property edge running perpendicular to the location I want to put the 4" pipe. I would like the 4" pipe to drain into the 12" pipe. What is the appropriate way to do so?

Some ideas:

Drill a hole into the sidewall of the 12" and allow 4" to fit horizontally into drilled hole so that 4" pipe drains into 12" pipe.

variation of #1 but with intentional "y" angle to allow incoming water to enter 12" pipe from uphill-to-downhill angle.

Bring 4" pipe over 12" pipe and connect from above (drill 4" hole into top of 12" pipe and let  4" pipe/connector extend vertically downward into 12" pipe

or is a coupling necessary? T or y?  (can I get a mixed-diameter coupling with mixed 12" and 4" ends??


Any suggestions?

The answer is: it depends what material the 12" pipe is.  Do you know?

@Huesmann finally found out: 12in pipe is black corrugated plastic

Then your course is probably to get a 12" tee and use reducers to connect the 4" to the 12" tee.  You might be able to find a reducing tee to minimize the number of reducers necessary, but I doubt you'll find one with a 4" stub.  The other option is to simply cut a 4" hole in the 12" pipe and encase the joint in concrete.  That would require excavating below the 12" pipe.
