Hole saw size for 4" corrugated pipe
I'm trying to connect a 4" corrugated (and perforated) HDPE plastic drain pipe into a 12" corrugated hdpe pipe.
what is the proper HOLE SAW bit to use for this?
Notes:

OD of 4" pipe is ~4.78"
"thickness" (OD-ID) of 12" pipe is ~2.3"


Do i just go up to a 5" bit? Or try to squeeze the pipe into a nearly as big 4-5/8" hole or 4.75" hole?

Can slice(cut) the smaller pipe to make it fit in a 4 inch hole up to a 4.75 hole.  You want some tension to the hole to hold it.

This doesn't sound like something within the "normal" realm of DIY work, with a 12" pipe.   What are you trying to accomplish?  Normally smaller drain lines are connected to a basin and that basin has a larger discharge conduit (pipe).

@RMDman trying to tie a French drain pipe into underground 12" storm sewer pipe to avoid digging my French drain another 60ft out to the road. (head of sewer dept gave me ok)

By slice I mean a single cut along the top, three or four inches or more.  Push one side of the cut under the other and squeeze sides to fit the hole size.

flexible or rigid 4" pipe?

seems similar to this other unanswered question. https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/302629/proper-way-to-connect-4-corrugated-drainage-pipe-into-perpendicular-12-pipe

@theforestecologist unless it's double-wall HDPE you could drill your 4" hole, then make many additional radial cuts (think like a pie, except the center of the pie has a hole) about 1/2" in length.  Then push your 4" pipe into the hole.  The "petals" of your cuts should flex, and help retain the 4" pipe in the hole.  But really the easy button is this: https://www.adspipe.com/resources/documents/BB6857C6-C803-41CA-B10E811D647EDBC2
